# BreezeJS wrong message for maxLength

Tags: validation, breeze

When you set a max length for a text field breeze sends back an incorrect validation message.  I have set a max length on my field that can contain 100 characters.  When I exceed this breeze returns the following validation error:

'subject' must be a string with less than 100 characters.

It should read:

'subject' must be a string with less than 101 characters.

or

'subject' must be a string with 100 characters or less.

Here is the problem code:

```
ctor.messageTemplates = {
    required: "'%displayName%' is required",
    date: "'%displayName%' must be a date",
    string: "'%displayName%' must be a string",
    bool: "'%displayName%' must be a 'true' or 'false' value",
    guid: "'%displayName%' must be a GUID",
    duration: "'%displayName%' must be a ISO8601 duration string, such as 'P3H24M60S'",
    number: "'%displayName%' must be a number",
    integer: "'%displayName%' must be an integer",
    integerRange: "'%displayName%' must be an integer between the values of %minValue% and %maxValue%",
    maxLength: "'%displayName%' must be a string with less than %maxLength% characters",
    stringLength: "'%displayName%' must be a string with between %minLength% and %maxLength% characters"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for letting us know!

We've fixed it and you will see the fix in our next release.